# imp/exp database in oracle

Tags: database, oracle, backup

I have dmp file for oracle database version "oracle orahome 81" and I want to import just the data not tables or views...etc coz I export the dmp file on pc1 ,and I want to import data on pc2 but pc2 already have old database and I wana to import  metadata to pc2 coz the database already exists so, when use this command :

```
imp username/password@orcl file=d:\backup.dmp full=y
```

**the error shown that I have already existed database so I cannot import new data to the pc2 
so how could solve these problem?**

Comment: 'i want to import just the data not tables or views' and 'i wana to import metadata' are contradictory. Assuming you do just want to import the data into the existing tables in PC2, are those tables empty, and if not will the new data co-exist with what's there or are you expecting it to be replaced? Showing sample errors using helps; in this case are you getting lots of 'object already exists' messages?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to specify indexes=N and constraints=N to ignore.

You can get available options for imp using

```
imp help=y
```

There is an option DATA_ONLY=Y, but i'm not sure it is exist in your oracle version.

Answer (score 1):

If the objects already exist and they are empty, or the data you're importing can safely be imported in addition to what is already there, you can use the [IGNORE flag](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/original_import.htm#autoId38):

> Specifies how object creation errors should be handled. If you accept
>   the default, `IGNORE=n`, then Import logs or displays object creation
>   errors before continuing.
>
> If you specify `IGNORE=y`, then Import overlooks object creation errors
>   when it attempts to create database objects, and continues without
>   reporting the errors.

There is no option to remove existing data during the import, so if there is existing data and you want it to be replaced, you'll need to empty the tables first (probably with `truncate`). Obviously make sure you really don't want anything you're going to remove.